# C++ Conceptual Question: Why can't I use a partially finished abstract class?

Tags: c++, class, abstract

I'am working on an abstract class, which later will be derived by several subclasses. However, pretty much of the functionality is non-abstract - so why can't I allocate an object of this abstract class and work with it, as long as I don't call any of the pure virtual functions? After all, the size of the abstract class is well known at compile time!?

Comment: Let's say I'm devoloping a class "Shape" with lots of functionality, but only one pure abstract function "draw". Before starting to make subclasses, I want to test the whole rest - for that I don't care about drawing for a while... Right now, I have to invent some subclass with a mock draw function to start working... it's a bit of a nuisance...

Comment: Factor the non-abstract parts into a non-abstract base class for testing.

Comment: Yep, it's not great for testing. You could add an assert to the base version of Shape::draw. And make it not pure virtual. I'm sure someone will be hired to kill me for saying this, but another approach would be to use a generate test class macro, that takes the class and all pure virtuals as arguments. You could also template specialise your pure virtuals but that feels like even more effort than making a special test class.

Comment: An abstract class, the functionality of which is non-abstract? Looks like a code smell to me. That very description implies at least 2 separate responsibilities for that single class, violating SOLID principle #1.

Comment: I don't think you can get a decisive answer so long as your description is quite so abstract (pun intended). I'm inclined to say this is indicative of some poor design choice, but that's hardly an answer one can derive useful ideas from.

Comment: And the conceptual problem may not even be with your class, but rather with your ideas about testing. You may be hung up on testing implementation-details instead of behavior, so you *think* you should be able to create a standalone object of that class, when in fact you can test the component this class belongs to reliably without resorting to it.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of abstract class is as:

> Defines an abstract type which cannot be instantiated, but can be used as a base class.

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class

To use it in another way would go against the use of abstract classes.

> Abstract classes are used to represent general concepts (for example, Shape, Animal), which can be used as base classes for concrete classes (for example, Circle, Dog).

> No objects of an abstract class can be created (except for base subobjects of a class derived from it) and no non-static data members of an abstract class can be declared.

See also https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.abstract

Answer (score 1):

> as long as I don't call any of the pure virtual functions?

Except in trivial cases, this can be impossible to prove. Let's look at an example. Suppose this is your abstract class

```
class Abby { virtual void fun() const = 0; };
```

and suppose you are able to create an `Abby` object for testing.

```
// First source file
Abby test;
```

In a trivial case, you literally do nothing with this object except cast it to `void` to avoid a compiler warning about an unused variable. In a non-trivial case, you might pass this object (by reference) to a function defined in **a different file** than the one where the object is created, perhaps the following function.

```
// Second source file
void foo(const Abby & o)
{
    o.fun();
}
```

This function expects an object that has `Abby` as a base class, and calls that object's virtual function. This works as long as it is forbidden to create an `Abby` object directly. If you relax this restriction, what happens? Should the compiler flag `foo()` as potentially broken because of what you might do in another translation unit? Should the compiler ignore the situation, leading to a runtime error?

Or maybe you would want a call to `foo(test)` to be flagged as making the definition of `test` to be invalid? This would be rather strange, to have the validity of one line (`Abby test;`) be dependent on what comes after it. It would also greatly limit what you could do in your test, leading compilers to ask why they bother. There is so little benefit to bending the rules this way, so why make a complicated language even more complicated?

---

Besides, it does not take much programming work to get the result you are looking for. Just comment out the pure virtual function.

```
class Abby { /* virtual void fun() const = 0; */ };
```

Since you're not calling it, this should not affect your code, right? If it does you could instead dummy-up the function, as in

```
class Abby { virtual void fun() const {} };
```

Revert this change once you are done testing.

*Personally I might derive a class from `Abby` with a dummy `fun()` member, and use that concrete class for testing instead of the abstract class. However, the OP called that "a nuisance" in a comment.*

```
class Concrete : public Abby { void fun() const override {} };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally get it. However, one could still argue that the compiler shouldn't prevent this at all (e.g. just issue a warning), instead the whole stuff would (rightfully) crash at runtime if someone called a pure virtual function!

Comment: @PeterLeikauf, we want a compiler to help us to avoid errors. The cons of that proposal would far outweigh its pros. For a similar reasons in C++ there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to `T*` (in contrast to C).

Comment: @Evg, yes, I know. On the other hand - if you look at all the errors you've ever made - how likely is it that you ever forgot to derive from an abstract class and used the base class instead? That would be a most exotic type of error IMHO. But ok, I agree that probably the cons would outweigh the flexibility.

Comment: @PeterLeikauf You can argue for lots of things. However, arguing that a (rather clear) compile-time error should instead become a (probably mysterious) runtime error would seem to be moving in the wrong direction. Especially when the usecase that would benefit is testing, not production.

Comment: @JaMiT I agree. After reading all the answers, I think my best course of action for testing purposes is to replace the pure virtual function by a non-pure that crashes & complains. Thanks!

Comment: Accidentally instantiating an abstract base class is a common error, at least in Windows: The base class is an interface, and the derived class is the hidden implementation. Somebody instantiates the derived class and returns a pointer to the base (interface) class. Everybody is supposed to operate with the interface pointer, but if you forget and try to instantiate the interface, you get an error because the interface is abstract. (If you want to be able to instantiate the abstract class, then just don't make it abstract. Give the methods dummy implementations that crash.)